# rich text editor vs update panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, yui, rich-text-editor

I have used the [YUI rich text editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/). I created a form with update panel. Then I found the YUI editor is not working fine in update panel. How can i do to work the yui editor within update panel?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use `Editor` control available in `AjaxControlToolKit`. It will work with `UpdatePanel` perfectly.

Comment: but I don't use this because of my conditionally case.

Comment: @zanhtet: are you using `ToolkitScriptManager` or `ScriptManager`  ? try to exchange it.